# R - can I stop the rattle package from starting up X11 on Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, x11, rattle

I am wondering if there is a way to load the `rattle` package in R without having to start up X11 - specifically on Mac OS X 10.11 (running R 3.2.3 / RStudio 0.99.486).

Right now, X11 starts up whenever I load the rattle package and destroys the battery on my laptop. Manually, shutting down X11 while RStudio is running crashes RStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rattle needs XQuartz in order to run.  It uses GTK to draw the windows which in turn uses X11/XQuartz.